# Google Script Send Email with Blob as "Body"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to send an email with the data from a certain google doc as the email body, I do NOT want to send it as attachment it specifically has to be in the body as text.
I've tried already the following:

```
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
 var fileBlob = file.getBlob();
 var blobToString = fileblob.toString();
 MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,blobToString);
```

It sends an email containing `function () { [native code] }` in the body.

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the blob as text, I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some code samples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is your file a Google Docs document?

Comment: @CarlosM yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

The simplest way to do this is to use `DocumentApp` methods to get the body of the document and get the text.

**For example**, in this *very simple* Google Docs:

[image]

You can use this script to get the text. Replace `doc-id` with the document ID.

```
function getText() {
  var document = DocumentApp.openById("<doc-id>");
  var text = document.getBody().getText();
}
```

**Sample Result: (dump into log)**

[image]

**References:**

[Class Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody)

[Class Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body)

**P.S.** Please note that this is a very bare bones solution. Please take your time to explore the references to get text information from other structural elements like tables or headers/footers.

Comment: Very much appreciated. Welcome to StackOverflow!